# How to use the SquaredError brick in Blocks (Theano, Python)?

Tags: python, block, theano

I designed a really simple recurrent neural network in Blocks (and Theano). As a cost function I decided to use the square error function which is defined simply  as `(y-y')^2`. I would like to compute the average cost across the minibatch.

The following code is an almost working example with Blocks class/method `SquaredError` which is, as far as I'm concerned, supposed to do exactly the desired operation.

*Please ignore inefficient `float64`, I use them in order to simplify `eval` execution. The problem preserves when using 32b*.

```
import theano.tensor as tt
from blocks.bricks.cost import SquaredError

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = tt.vector('a', dtype='float64')
    b = tt.vector('b', dtype='float64')

    cost = SquaredError().apply(a, b)

    print(cost.eval({a: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
                     b: [0.5, 2.1, 3.4, 3.8]}))

    # Expected: mean(0.5^2 + 0.1^2 + 0.4^2 + 0.2^2)
    # Got: ValueError: Not enough dimensions on squarederror_cost_matrix_output_0 to reduce on axis 1
```

If I change the problematic line into the one below, everything works as expected.

```
cost = tt.sqr(tt.abs_(a - b)).mean()
```

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to learn Blocks more but this is beyond my understanding. Am I supposed to use another brick? Or somehow preprocess the tensors?

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though we require 2D inputs for CostMatrix bricks, which is kind of dumb. I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/mila-udem/blocks/issues/1083) about it. You can get around this, if you like, by dimshuffling your inputs up to (N, 1) matrices, but the Cost bricks are mainly only useful if you're using the automatic tagging of inputs and outputs for VariableFilter operations, etc. Writing down the cost as you did in a Theano expression is fine too (although to nitpick you don't need the abs, the square of a negative number is always positive anyway).

Comment: P.S. Blocks isn't really popular enough for us to actively monitor StackOverflow, you can try us on the blocks-users Google group for general open-ended usage questions or the issue tracker if something is clearly broken.

Comment: Thanks for clarification and the issue creation. Next time I will use the user group instead of SO.